# Kernel appears to have no modules

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

**Useful info:**

```
OS: CentOS 5.8 final
Kernel: 2.6.32-042stab056.8
```

My kernel came prebuilt with the server, I don't know anything about kernels and not a lot about linux however as far as I do know I should have some modules loaded by the kernel.

I came across this problem because I am unable to run `iscsi` as it is expecting certain modules to be loaded.

`lsmod` returns nothing.

`depmod -a` returns:

```
WARNING: Couldn't open directory /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8/modules.dep.temp for writing: No such file or directory
```

I have rebooted and nothing has changed.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is this useful? https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/vps/modprobe-fatal-count-not-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is broken. The `/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab056.8` directory should be populated with module files, but it clearly isn't. Chances are your kernel RPM didn't install correctly. I suggest forcibly re-applying it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions, however I have no idea what I am doing with this and don't want to break everything. (I am very new to linux and the terminal) is there any walkthrough you know of for doing this?

Comment: If `yum reinstall kernel` doesn't do it for you, you're beyond walk-through.

Comment: `yum reinstall kernel` installed a different version and my system isn't picking up on it, still thinks it is the old version. I also think the version it installed doesn't support `SMP`

Comment: @GeorgeReith You'll need a reboot for them to synchronize. When you install a new kernel, the module FILES for the old one go away but modules STILL LOADED are still loaded. When you reboot, it should pick up the new kernel files and modules.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, `yum reinstall kernel` returns `Package(s) kernel available, but not installed.` so my current kernel version is not in any yum repo. However `yum install kernel` works and adds the new kernel but doesn't replace the old version even after a reboot.

Comment: Are you all sure that this might not be a static kernel, afterall the user seems to imply that operations are proceeding normally (an assumption on my part).  I know statically linked kernels might be rare these days.

Comment: @mpdc That was my first thought too, but I've never run into one that came pre-packaged from a major vendor. This kernel is a [non-standard kernel](http://wiki.openvz.org/Download/kernel/rhel6-testing/042stab056.8), but all signs point to dynamic.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling CentOS (and upgrading to 6.2) which came with the same kernel, and all the modules are there now.